# Eigenvector of shift operator with tiny eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

For $0<\lambda<1$, consider the operator 
$$A=(S_L+\lambda)(S_R+\lambda),$$ 
where $S_L,S_R$ are the left-shift and right-shift operators on $\mathbb{C}^n$ with nontrivial kernel (open boundary conditions). I'm looking for an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue exponentially decaying to $0$ as $n\to \infty$.

How do I solve for this special eigenvector?

Comment: Notably, the matrix for $A$ is tridiagonal, and given by
$$
\pmatrix{I_{n-1}&0\\0&0} + \lambda(S + S^T)  + \lambda^2 I 
$$
where $S$ is the matrix associated with the left shift operator, given by
$$
S = \pmatrix{0&1\\&0&1\\&&\ddots\\ &&&&1\\&&&&0}
$$

Comment: It may also be useful to consider the operator in question as a rank-1 perturbation from a circulant matrix

Comment: I'm interested in the details - how does this uncover the low-eigenvalue eigenvector?

Comment: Oh, I meant Toeplitz, not circulant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be the matrix given by $M = (1+\lambda^2) I + \lambda(S + S^T)$, with $S$ as in my comment above.  We note that $M$ is [tridiagonal and Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues), which means its eigenvalues are given nicely as
$$
\mu_k = (1+\lambda^2) + 2\lambda\cos(k\pi/(n+1)), \quad k =1 , \dots ,n
$$
Let $e$ denote the column vector $e = (0,\dots,0,1)$, so that $A = M - ee^T$.

By the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), we may state that for any $\nu$:
$$
\det(A - \nu I)  = \det((M - \nu I) - ee^T) = (1 - e^T(M - \nu I)^{-1}e)\det(M - \nu I)
$$
In other words: suppose that $\nu$ is not an eigenvalue of $M$.  Then $\nu$ will be an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if the $n,n$ entry if $(M - \nu I)^{-1}$ is equal to $1$.  Alternatively, the adjugate version yields
$$
\det((M - \nu I) - ee^T) = \det(M - \nu I) - e^TAdj(M - \nu I)e
$$
which yields an interesting condition: $\nu$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if
$$
\det(M - \nu I) = \det([M - \nu I][1,\dots,n-1;1,\dots,n-1])
$$
where $[M - \nu I][1,\dots,n-1;1,\dots,n-1]$ denotes the submatrix in which the last row and column of $M$ are deleted.

This will eventually lead to the characteristic polynomial of $A$, but that might not be so helpful.

Comment: Another approach is to simply find a bound on the absolute value of that lowest eigenvalue using [Weyl's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl.27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory).  On the downside, that makes it very difficult to extract an eigenvector.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll have to examine it for a while to see if I can solve for the eigenvector this way. But I'll definitely accept it after I understand it.